# Salesforce Developer Wiki Retirement

Tags: discussion

Years ago, the Salesforce developer wiki was a trove of valuable technical resources but nowadays there is a good part of those 1.6K pages that is obsolete and duplicated by our documentation. As a consequence, we felt that it was time to act for the sake of the quality and relevance of our technical resources.

After more than a decade of loyal services it is now time to retire the Salesforce Developer Wiki.

Over the last few months, we've been scaling down the importance of the wiki by gradually unlinking it from our other sites. However, search engines keep on redirecting users to wiki content so we now need to make the final push and fully decommission it.

> If you're uncertain what part of developer.salesforce.com comprises the wiki, if the url was in the `page` resource, it was in the wiki. For instance https://developer.salesforce.com/page/App_Logic would be one such url.

## History

The Salesforce Developer Wiki was created more than ten years ago. It used to be the developer documentation but it was also used for other secondary purposes such as tutorials, blog posts and surveys.

[image: Developer Wiki Categories]

What was great about it was that the fact that it was written collaboratively by the community. This gave us good content with diverse point of views from a great variety of sources. Unfortunately, this collaborative nature also led to it's downfall as it takes several full time jobs, some processes, and a robust strategy to structure and maintain such vast content. For example: each new release requires a plan and resources to systematically review existing content and develop new content for newly released features.

As our company grew, we put in place strong content delivery and maintenance processes with dedicated documentation teams. We increasingly focused on internally maintained documentation sites while reducing our efforts around the wiki. We felt that third party sites and blog would continue to provide diverse insights but that we needed to *enforce content quality* and streamline coverage of our features.

## Our plan

The developer wiki still holds unique and valuable content so we are taking care of preserving this precious knowledge. After carefully reviewing its content, we ended up redirecting and transferring most of it between:

- [Developer Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/)
- [Help & Training](http://help.salesforce.com/)
- [Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/)
- [Salesforce Developer Centers](https://developer.salesforce.com/devcenter/)

We investigated and retired more than a hundred developer wiki links from 41 Trailhead modules and projects. This initiative guarantees the quality of your learning experience after we fully decommission the developer wiki.

## Stack Exchange Links

We expect there to be a large number of links on StackExchange that refer to the wiki. For this reason and for the sake of transparency we wanted to post here. Retirement of pages will begin this week on 22 August. *Starting then, about 70% of all pages will redirect to new content.*

*Page retirement will continue for several months. This will include Roughly 25% of pages which are completely obsolete and will be decommissioned.  The remaining 5% of pages with current/active content will be moved to new homes.*

## Share your feedback

We would love to hear from you. Feel free to share your developer wiki experience and thoughts on this Salesforce Stack Exchange Meta post.

**** Updated Text in *Italics* to clarify on redirects versus removal. ****

Comment: If there is a way on your end to identify the most common referrers and post them as an ordered list sorted by reference count, that would help tremendously to mitigate the damage.

Comment: I can look into it. Let me reach out to the site infrastructure team and see what we could pull.

Comment: @AdrianLarson I was also wondering whether moderator tools had any way to parse links in SFSE markdown. Like was there a way to determine which among the _n_ most popular articles had links to urls with that resource in them. ;

Comment: Nope we don't have any such special tools that I'm aware of. You might be able to work some SOQL magic on the query explorer.

Comment: Well...in any case, I've put the question to the infra team. We'll see what they come back with.

Comment: @AdrianLarson query using LIKE, grep, sort, done.

Comment: Thank you for reaching out to us with this @pchittum

Comment: Heads up I learned my information on retirement was slightly off (second day back from vacation...my apologies.) I've clarified which pages will be acted upon immediately (only the redirects). And which will be taken down in due course.

Comment: I noticed that there is no redirect for How to Write Good Unit Tests, a resource we recommend pretty often. Was that content completely retired? That would be a shame.

Comment: @pchittum, I should have tagged you in the above.

Comment: Great feedback, @DavidReed. Kevin Poorman undertook an extensive project to create a decently comprehensive module on Trailhead. I'd be interested to hear how you think it stacks up: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/unit-testing-on-the-lightning-platform

Comment: @pchittum Thanks, I had missed the release of that module! It aligns really nicely with the Month of Testing blog series. I think my only qualm is that How to Write Good Unit Tests was a different kind of content - long-form, text-primary, detailed, engineering focused. The Trailhead module covers a ton of content effectively, but its more structurally complex - multimedia, divided into units (ironic, that), interactive, and less amenable to purely reference and random access use cases. I think the two forms of presentation complement one another well.

Comment: The one thing I thought the Trailhead module could cover with some more detail (disclaimer: I didn't watch the videos, *pace* above comment!) is isolation and tracing of logic paths. We get a lot of intro questions where people don't get why different logic branches are not covered, or control structures don't get entered by test execution. The module *does* touch on this but I thought more close analysis might help those who don't have a lot of programming experience.

Comment: In any case, I'll make sure it gets linked several times in the unit-test-focused canonical questions we're working on.

Comment: I'll see that Kevin gets the feedback and loop in our blog content roadmap team. We have been using more evergreen blog posts as a place to put some of these topics. Maybe that can be added.

Answer (score 11):

There are currently [1540 posts](https://data.stackexchange.com/salesforce/query/888837/posts-that-contain-urls-that-are-being-decommissioned-by-salesforce) that match the URL pattern '%developer.salesforce.com/page%'. It would have been nice to have more than a 2 day head start on this project. If you have a translation table of what goes where, that would help us update the links appropriately.

There are currently **340 unique links** to the wiki that I found based on this query:

- developer.salesforce.com/page/A_Deeper_look_at_SOQL_and_Relationship_Queries_on_Force.com
- developer.salesforce.com/page/A_Deeper_look_at_SOQL_and_Relationship_Queries_on_Force.com#Left_Anti_Join
- developer.salesforce.com/page/A_Deeper_look_at_SOQL_and_Relationship_Queries_on_Force.com#Left_Inner_Join
- developer.salesforce.com/page/A_Deeper_look_at_SOQL_and_Relationship_Queries_on_Force.com#Left_Outer_Join
- developer.salesforce.com/page/A_Deeper_look_at_SOQL_and_Relationship_Queries_on_Force.com#Right_Inner_Join
- developer.salesforce.com/page/A_Deeper_look_at_SOQL_and_Relationship_Queries_on_Force.com#Right_Outer_Join
- developer.salesforce.com/page/A_Guide_to_Application_Performance_Profiling_in_Force.com
- developer.salesforce.com/page/A_Guide_to_Sharing_Architecture
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Accessing_Salesforce_Data_From_Ruby
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Adding_CAPTCHA_to_Force.com_Sites
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Additional_detail
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Adobe_Flash_Builder_for_Force.com_FAQ
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Adobe_XFDF
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Ajax_Proxy
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Amazon_Toolkit
- developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Apex
- developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Apex_Code_Test_Methods
- developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_To_Email_Services_on_Force.com
- developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Environments
- developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Exception_Handling
- developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Force.com_Metadata
- developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Force.com_Sites
- developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Force.com_Sites#Syndication_Feeds
- developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Force_Database
- developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Force_IDE
- developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Formulas
- developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Packaging
- developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Salesforce_Chatter
- developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Salesforce_to_Salesforce
- developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Visualforce
- developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Visualforce_View_State
- developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Visualforce_View_State#Consider_Doing_Your_Own_State_Management_in_Certain_Cases
- developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Visualforce_View_State#Refactor_Your_Pages_to_Make_Its_View_Stateless
- developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Overview_of_Force.com_Security
- developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Overview_of_Force.com_Security#Record-based_Sharing
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Callouts
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Code:_The_Basics
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Code:_The_Basics#Case_Sensitivity
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Code:_The_Basics#Expression_Composition_and_Operators
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Code_Best_Practices
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Code_Best_Practices#Best_Practices_.2310:_Avoid_Hardcoding_IDs
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Crypto_Class
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Design_Patterns
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Design_Patterns#Composite
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Design_Patterns#Singleton
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Enterprise_Patterns_-_Domain_Layer
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Enterprise_Patterns_-_Selector_Layer
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Enterprise_Patterns_-_Separation_of_Concerns
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Enterprise_Patterns_-_Service_Layer
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Testing_with_RunAs
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Testing_with_RunAs?language=en
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Web_Services
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Web_Services_and_Callouts
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Web_Services_and_Callouts#Apex_Callouts
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Web_Services_and_Callouts#Apex_Web_Services
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Web_Services_and_Callouts#HTTP_.28RESTful.29_Services
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Web_Services_and_Callouts#HTTP_Header_Support
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Web_Services_and_Callouts#Supported_WSDL_Features
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Web_Services_and_Callouts#WSDL2Apex
- developer.salesforce.com/page/App_Distribution
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Application_Framework
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Approval_Processes
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Architect_Core_Resources
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Asynchronous_Processing_in_Force_com
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Asynchronous_Processing_in_Force_com#Batch_Apex
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Authenticating_Users_on_Force.com_Sites
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Auto-completion_Resolution_Time_Milestones_with_Triggers
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Autocreating_Contacts_From_Web_To_Case
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Best_Practice%3a_Avoid_SOQL_Queries_Inside_FOR_Loops
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Best_Practice%3a_Bulkify_Your_Code
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Best_Practice%3A_Bulkify_Your_Code
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Best_Practice:_Avoid_Hardcoding_IDs
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Best_Practice:_Avoid_SOQL_Queries_Inside_FOR_Loops
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Best_Practice:_Bulkify_Your_Code
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Best_Practice:_Streamline_Multiple_Triggers_on_same_Object
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Best_Practice:_Use_future_Appropriately
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Best_Practice:_Use_of_the_Limits_Apex_Methods_to_avoid_Hitting_Governor_Limits
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Best_Practices_for_Deployments_with_Large_Data_Volumes
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Best_Practices_for_Salesforce_to_Salesforce
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Best_Practices_for_Salesforce_to_Salesforce#Best_Practice:_Automatically_share_new_accounts
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Building_a_Mobile_SDK_Hybrid_App_for_Android
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Building_Single_Page_Apps_with_JavaScript_and_Visualforce_Remote_Objects
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Building_Visualforce_Pages_Using_the_Standard_Controller
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Building_Visualforce_Pages_Using_the_Standard_Controller#CONTROLLING_DATA
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Building_Visualforce_Pages_Using_the_Standard_Controller#Referencing_a_Single_Record
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Bulk_API
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Case_Milestones_Utilities_Class
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Chatter_API
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Chatter_API:_Examples,_Best_Practices,_and_Tips
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Chatter_Code_Recipes
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Cheat_Sheets
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Code_Sample_-_Creating_Ideas_from_inbound_emails_using_Email_Services
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Code_Sample_-_Testing_Email_Services_with_Inbound_Attachments
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Code_Samples
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Code_Samples#Parse_a_CSV_with_APEX
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Concurrent-Sessions
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Configuring-SAML-SSO-to-Citrix
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Configuring-SAML-SSO-to-Custom-.Net-Application
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Configuring-SAML-SSO-to-ExactTarget
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Connected_Apps
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Connecting_Force.com_to_Azure_Service_Bus_Part2
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Consuming_Force.com_SOAP_and_REST_Web_Services_from_.NET_Applications
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Continuous_Integration_Cruise_Control_and_Force_Com
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Continuous_Integration_How-To
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Controller_Component_Communication
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Creating_an_Outbound_Messaging_Notification_Service_with_Eclipse_3.2
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Creating_Custom_Web-To-Case_Forms_Using_Visualforce_and_Sites
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Creating_Professional_PDF_Documents_with_CSS_and_Visualforce
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Creating_REST_APIs_using_Apex_REST
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Creating_REST_APIs_using_Apex_REST#Using_GET_and_DELETE
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Creating_REST_APIs_using_Apex_REST#Using_POST.2C_PUT_and_PATCH
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Creating_REST_APIs_using_Apex_REST/
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Data_Integration
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Data_Loader
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Data_Loader.
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Data_Loader_and_relationships
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Declarative_Rollup_Summary_Tool_for_Force.com_Lookup_Relationships
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Delivering_Static_Resources_with_Visualforce
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Deploy_Force.com_Applications_Faster
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Developer_Console
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Developer_Edition
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Developer_Library
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Developing_Apps_with_jQuery
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Developing_Hybrid_Apps_with_the_Salesforce_Mobile_SDK
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Developing_Offline_Apps_with_SmartStore
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Developing_Selective_Force.com_Queries_through_the_Query_Resource_Feedback_Parameter_Pilot
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Developing_Selective_Force.com_Queries_through_the_Query_Resource_Feedback_Parameter_Pilot#CompositeIndexJoins
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Developing_Selective_Force.com_Queries_through_the_Query_Resource_Feedback_Parameter_Pilot#InefficientOperators
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Developing_Selective_Force.com_Queries_through_the_Query_Resource_Feedback_Parameter_Pilot#Unions
- developer.salesforce.com/page/DevelopingWithServiceAndSupport
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Digging_Deeper_into_OAuth_2.0_at_Salesforce.com
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Digging_Deeper_into_OAuth_2.0_on_Force.com
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Digging_Deeper_into_OAuth_2.0_on_Force.com#Configuring_OAuth_2.0_Access_for_your_Application
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Digging_Deeper_into_OAuth_2.0_on_Force.com#Obtaining_a_Token_in_an_Autonomous_Client_.28Username_and_Password_Flow.29
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Digging_Deeper_into_OAuth_2.0_on_Force.com#Obtaining_an_Access_Token_in_a_Browser_or_Native_Application_.28User-Agent_Flow.29
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Digging_Deeper_into_OAuth_2.0_on_Force.com#Obtaining_an_Access_Token_in_a_Web_Application_.28Web_Server_Flow.29
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Digging_Deeper_into_OAuth_2.0_on_Force.com#Obtaining_an_Access_Token_using_a_JWT_Bearer_Token
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Digging_Deeper_into_OAuth_2.0_on_Force.com#Obtaining_an_Access_Token_using_a_SAML_Bearer_Assertion
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Digging_Deeper_into_OAuth_2.0_on_Force.com#Obtaining_an_Access_Token_using_a_SAML_Bearer_Assertion.
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Digging_Deeper_into_OAuth_2.0_on_Force.com#The_Force.com_Identity_Service
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Digging_Deeper_into_OAuth_2.0_on_Force.com#Token_Refresh
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Dynamic_Visualforce_Components
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Earlier_Reference_Documentation
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Enforcing_CRUD_and_FLS
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Enforcing_Encryption
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Enterprise_Login
- developer.salesforce.com/page/ExampleApexCustomerPortalUser
- developer.salesforce.com/page/FAQ_Practical_Overview_of_Building_Apps_on_Force.com#Q:_Are_record_ids_unique_per_organization_or_unique_across_all_tenants.3F
- developer.salesforce.com/page/File:Apex_code_testing_webinar.pdf
- developer.salesforce.com/page/File:Idpsp.png
- developer.salesforce.com/page/File:OAuthWebServerFlow.png
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Force.com_Books
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Force.com_Canvas
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Force.com_CI_Using_AWS,_Github_and_Jenkins
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Force.com_Dynamic_Approval_Routing
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Force.com_Excel_Connector
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Force.com_IDE
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Force.com_IDE_Installation
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Force.com_IDE_Release_Notes
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Force.com_Migration_Tool
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Force.com_Sites_Best_Practices
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Force.com_Toolkit_for_PHP
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Force.com_workbook
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Force_Platform_Fundamentals
- developer.salesforce.com/page/ForceExplorer
- developer.salesforce.com/page/From_SQL_to_SOQL
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Generating_and_Loading_Representative_Test_Data_for_Salesforce_and_Force.com_Orgs
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Getting_Started_with_Apex_JSON
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Getting_Started_with_the_Force.com_REST_API
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Getting_Started_with_the_Force.com_Streaming_API
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Getting_Started_with_the_Force.com_Toolkit_for_PHP
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Getting-Started-With-Apple-Watch-Devkit
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Google_Calendar_API
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Google_Data_API_Toolkit
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Google_Data_APIs_Toolkit_Setup#Checking_Out_the_Force.com_Toolkit_for_Google_Data_APIs
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Google_Visualizations
- developer.salesforce.com/page/How_to_Implement_Single_Sign-On_with_Force.com
- developer.salesforce.com/page/How_To_Test_Your_Apex_Triggers
- developer.salesforce.com/page/How_to_Write_Good_Unit_Tests
- developer.salesforce.com/page/How_to_Write_Good_Unit_Tests#The_Value_of_Unit_Tests
- developer.salesforce.com/page/How_to_Write_Good_Unit_Tests#Verify_the_results_are_correct
- developer.salesforce.com/page/identity
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Identity
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Implementing_SAML_SSO_for_Canvas_Apps
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Implementing_Single_Sign-On_Across_Multiple_Organizations
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Inside_OpenID_Connect_on_Force.com
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Installing_Force_for_Amazon_Web_Services
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Integrating_Force.com_with_Microsoft_.NET
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Integrating_Java_Spring_Apps_on_Heroku_with_Force.com_REST_APIs
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Integrating_with_the_Force.com_Platform
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Integration
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Introduction_to_Controllers_and_Extensions
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Introduction_to_the_Force.com_Web_Services_Connector
- developer.salesforce.com/page/ISVPlatformEncryption#Can.27t_reference_encrypted_fields_in_Formula_Field_Types
- developer.salesforce.com/page/ISVPlatformEncryption#Key_limitations_and_their_workarounds
- developer.salesforce.com/page/ISVPlatformEncryption#Six_steps_process_to_adapt_your_package_to_Shield_Platform_Encryption
- developer.salesforce.com/page/ISVPlatformEncryption#What_is_Shield_Platform_Encryption.3F
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Java
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Java_Partner_WSDL_Samples_10.0
- developer.salesforce.com/page/JavaScript
- developer.salesforce.com/page/JP%3aForce_Platform_Cookbook
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Lightning_Connect
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Lightning_Experience_FAQ
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Lightning_FAQ
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Lightning_FAQ#Visualforce_and_Lightning
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Lightning_Open_CTI
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Lightning_Process_Builder
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Lightning_Security
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Lightning_Security#CRUD.2FFLS_Enforcement
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Loading_Large_Data_Sets_with_the_Force.com_Bulk_API
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Login_with_Azure_AD
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Login_with_Google
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Login_with_LinkedIn
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Login-Flows
- developer.salesforce.com/page/MakeTopic-Bonus-Streaming.java
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Making_A_Spreadsheet_On_Force.com
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Making_Authenticated_Web_Service_Callouts_Using_Two-Way_SSL
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Metadata_Create_Custom_Field
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Migration_Tool_Guide
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Miscellaneous
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Mobile_SDK
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Multi_Tenant_Architecture
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Multi_Tenant_Architecture#Multitenant_Search_Processing
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Native,_HTML5,_or_Hybrid:_Understanding_Your_Mobile_Application_Development_Options
- developer.salesforce.com/page/News
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Nonprofit_Starter_Pack
- developer.salesforce.com/page/OAuthServlet.java
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Open_CTI
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Open_CTI/%22link%20to%20doc%22
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Outbound_Messaging_SSL_CA_Certificates
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Outbound_Messaging_SSL_CA_Certificates#addtrustclass1ca
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Outbound_Messaging_SSL_CA_Certificates#geotrustglobalca
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Outbound_Messaging_SSL_CA_Certificates#godaddy
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Outbound_Messaging_SSL_CA_Certificates#godaddyrootg2ca
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Outbound_Messaging_SSL_CA_Certificates#thawteprimaryrootca
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Paginating_Data_for_Force.com_Applications
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Partner_Development_%26_Test_Environments
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Partner_Development_&_Test_Environments
- developer.salesforce.com/page/PartnerLogin
- developer.salesforce.com/page/PHP_Toolkit
- developer.salesforce.com/page/PHP_Toolkit_11.0_SendEmail_Sample_(Enterprise)
- developer.salesforce.com/page/PHP_Toolkit_13.0_Create_Delete_Undelete_Sample_(Enterprise)
- developer.salesforce.com/page/PHP_Toolkit_13.0_Getting_Started
- developer.salesforce.com/page/PHP_Toolkit_20.0_ConvertLead_Sample_(Enterprise)
- developer.salesforce.com/page/PHP_Toolkit_20.0_Create_Delete_Undelete_Sample_(Enterprise)
- developer.salesforce.com/page/PHP_Toolkit_20.0_Create_Delete_Undelete_Sample_(Partner)
- developer.salesforce.com/page/PHP_Toolkit_20.0_DescribeSObject_Sample_(Enterprise)
- developer.salesforce.com/page/PHP_Toolkit_20.0_FieldsToNull_Sample_(Partner)
- developer.salesforce.com/page/PHP_Toolkit_20.0_Login_Sample_%28Partner%29
- developer.salesforce.com/page/PHP_Toolkit_20.0_Login_Sample_(Partner)
- developer.salesforce.com/page/PHP_Toolkit_20.0_Metadata_Create_Sample
- developer.salesforce.com/page/PHP_Toolkit_20.0_Query_Sample_(Partner)
- developer.salesforce.com/page/PHP_Toolkit_20.0_Samples
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Platform_Security_FAQS
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Propagating_Destructive_Changes
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Publish_Your_First_App_with_AppExchange_Checkout
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Quick_Tutorial_1:_Build_a_Cloud_App_in_5_Minutes
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Requirements_Checklist
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Requirements_Checklist?language=en
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Requirements_Checklist?language=en&language=en
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Responsive_Design_with_Twitter_Bootstrap_and_Visualforce
- developer.salesforce.com/page/REST_API
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Salesforce_APIs
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Salesforce_as_an_Identity_Provider_for_Customer_Portal
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Salesforce_Backup_and_Restore_Essentials_Part_1
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Salesforce_Backup_and_Restore_Essentials_Part_1?utm_campaign=LightningWeek&utm_source=Newsletter_031015&utm_medium=Chief_Editor&eid=singlesend
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Salesforce_IdP_Setup
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Salesforce_Reports_for_Excel_%28Pilot%29
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Sample_SOAP_Messages
- developer.salesforce.com/page/S-Control_Deprecation
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Secure_Coding_Arbitrary_Redirect
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Secure_Coding_Cross_Site_Request_Forgery
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Secure_Coding_Cross_Site_Request_Forgery#Apex_and_Visualforce_Application
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Secure_Coding_Cross_Site_Scripting
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Secure_Coding_Cross_Site_Scripting#HTMLENCODE
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Secure_Coding_Cross_Site_Scripting#S-Control_Template_and_Formula_Tags
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Secure_Coding_Cross_Site_Scripting#Unsafe_sObject_Data_Types
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Secure_Coding_Guideline
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Secure_Coding_Single_Sign_On
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Secure_Coding_SQL_Injection
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Secure_Coding_SQL_Injection#Apex_and_Visualforce_Applications
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Secure_Coding_Storing_Secrets
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Secure_Coding_Storing_Secrets#Apex_and_Visualforce_Applications
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Secure_Private_Trustworthy_Force.com_Whitepaper
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Security/Chimera
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Security_Review
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Security_Review#Scope
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Security_Review_FAQ
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Security_Review_Test_Info
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Security_Review_Test_Info#3._Documentation
- developer.salesforce.com/page/SFDC:Archived_Intro_to_Force.com:_Building_Composite_Apps
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Single_Sign_On_for_Composite_Apps
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Single_Sign-On_for_Desktop_and_Mobile_Applications_using_SAML_and_OAuth
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Single_Sign-On_with_Force.com_and_Microsoft_Active_Directory_Federation_Services
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Single_Sign-On_with_SAML_on_Force.com
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Sites
- developer.salesforce.com/page/SMS-2FA
- developer.salesforce.com/page/SOAP_API
- developer.salesforce.com/page/SOAP_Compression
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Specifying_Intermediate_CA_Certificates
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Streaming_Real_Time_Data_into_Visualforce
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Streaming_Real_Time_Data_into_Visualforce#Create_a_Push_Topic
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Summer07:_Update_Collision_Detection
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Synchronizing_Portal_Users_with_Contact_Record_Data
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Testing_CRUD_and_FLS_Enforcement
- developer.salesforce.com/page/The_Get_Next_Button
- developer.salesforce.com/page/The_Salesforce_Bulk_API_-_Maximizing_Parallelism_and_Throughput_Performance_When_Integrating_or_Loading_Large_Data_Volumes
- developer.salesforce.com/page/The_Salesforce_Bulk_API_-_Maximizing_Parallelism_and_Throughput_Performance_When_Integrating_or_Loading_Large_Data_Volumes#SerialLoad
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Tooling_API
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Tools
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Trigger_Frameworks_and_Apex_Trigger_Best_Practices
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Trigger_Frameworks_and_Apex_Trigger_Best_Practices#Logic-less_Triggers
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Trigger_Frameworks_and_Apex_Trigger_Best_Practices#One_Trigger_Per_Object
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Trigger_Handlers
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Troubleshooting_Apex_Performance_Problems
- developer.salesforce.com/page/UI_Testing
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Use_Salesforce_REST_API_with_Your_JavaServer_Pages
- developer.salesforce.com/page/User_Interface
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Using_Apex_Managed_Sharing_to_Create_Custom_Record_Sharing_Logic
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Using_Data_Loader_from_the_command_line
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Using_Data_Loader_from_the_command_line#The_files
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Using_Force.com_with_Subversion_for_Team_Development
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Using_Force_for_Amazon_Web_Services
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Using_Formulas_and_Google_Charts_to_Visualize_Data
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Using_OAuth_to_Authorize_External_Applications
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Visual_Workflow
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Visualforce_DynamicEditPage
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Visualforce_Quote2PDF
- developer.salesforce.com/page/VisualForceEmailTemplates_sample
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Webinar:_Inside_the_Force.com_Query_Optimizer_%282013-Apr%29
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Wiki
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Without_Sharing
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Workbench
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Workbench#Deploying_Workbench_to_Heroku
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Workbench#Installation
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Workbench#Login
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Workbench#Utilities
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Workflow_Rules
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Working_with_Custom_SOAP_and_REST_Services_in_.NET_Applications
- developer.salesforce.com/page/Wrapper_Class

Comment: @pchittum Is there a mapping for where these URLs should redirect to going forward? We could start swapping them out. Starting with the questions with the most views.

Comment: @DanielBallinger suggestion: try reaching out on twitter. Might get a better response. I have no problem editing ~1500 posts, it wouldn't be the first time I've done something crazy like that :D

Comment: Will do. I'd like to help with the effort, but I need to get my Dreamforce presentation completely finished before I start on anything else. I'll try Peter on twitter.

Comment: @DanielBallinger Have no fear, I intentionally skipped DF this year. I will solo it if need be. I just need to know where each link redirects to.

Comment: Hi folks. Good morning (UK time)! I would suggest that the pages that we're retiring as obsolete (no redirect) would be the first priority to remove those links from any posts. We are putting in place a custom 404 error page specifically for retired wiki pages, but better to minimize visits there. I don't expect there would be a problem to provide you our redirect mapping for the rest but just need to seek necessary approvals (wiki articles not on the redirect list are being retired as obsolete flat out).

Comment: Incidentally, I'm happy to help do my part as a member to do some clean up but I can't start until week of 27 Aug.

Comment: I'd be happy to help with editing the posts to fix any links that will be broken by this.

Comment: @sfdcfox heads up that I learned we are only acting on redirects this week. This reduces the urgency. Which is good as we're still working on the compiled list. Thanks, everyone.

Comment: @sfdcfox and other helpers, we're putting together a list of redirects as of now. Should have something early next week to work on.

Comment: @sfdcfox, I'm finally getting back to this after Dreamforce. The good news is we delayed this, but we're ramping back up again. Before we kick this off, maybe we could hop on a quick call and discuss the best way to go about this. Can you email me and we can set something up: pchittum@salesforce.com

Comment: @DaveHumm If you're still interested in helping, please reach out to me (email address in another comment above). I'll add you to the google sheet with the redirect URLs there. sfdxfox should also be able to add you.

Comment: @pchittum I couldn't find your email in the posts. Yes I am still interested in helping my ohana.

Comment: @DaveHumm You can choose to contact me if you like. Email is on my profile (click my username).

Comment: @DaveHumm let me know if you're sorted or not. My email address is in the comment four above this one.

Comment: @pchittum - sent you an email now. Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

I've started making some of the replacements based on the details provided by Peter.

I'm using the comments to direct back to this meta post to provide details on why the change is occurring.

> [Salesforce Developer Wiki Retirement](https://salesforce.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2780/102). Updating redirects to new pages.